# How to view the existing comments posted by user in map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I am creating a map application which is actually like a travelling guide that allows the users to get the directions, and the current location and the user can post a comment at a particular location and take or upload a picture at a particular location and save it to the map.

And it has feature that the user can review the comments posted by other user nearby to his current location. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a backend server, and implement your own web service or rest api for store location, picture, and review. You can choose GAE, EC2, etc.

Or, a more convenient choice, backend service for app. Like Parse, Kinvey, Cocoafish. Take a look at this link: [Cocoafish's Create Review Api Document](http://cocoafish.com/docs/api/v1/reviews/create)

You can call this api, let user post comment at particular photo or place.Then call their photo or place api to show what user want.